# Apply auto-layout to UITableViewCell based on it's parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` inside a `container view`. I am trying to apply `auto-layout` to the `cells` in the `tableView`. For example: I have 3 `cells`. The first and last one should have a set height (say 25), and the middle one should be dynamic based on the `view's` height. (The `tableView` is in the `container view`.)

I tried using `auto-layout`, but it wouldn't let me apply it. I can't use `heightForRow...` because the `views` height changes when the iPhones orientation changes.

My question is: how can I apply `auto-layout` to a cell?

Comment: can you post the screen shot of image you want to acheive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add support for dynamic cell size follow these steps:

1) Add the appropriate constraints to the cell, meaning do not setup fixed height for any of the views and add constraints for top and bottom space

In code you would add the subviews and constraints to `cell.contentView`, in storyboards just use a prototype cell.

2) Add these two lines to your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = tableView.rowHeight  
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: In step 1, do you mean add constraints to the tableView? Because I can't add constraints to the cell.

Comment: No, I mean the cell. Are you using storyboards or code?

Comment: I'm using static tableViewcells. When I select a cell, and do click "pin" (on the bottom right), I can't select anything in it.

Comment: you need to ctrl+drag from views in the cell or use "add suggested constraints".

Comment: I'm talking the cells itself. Not the views in it.

Comment: I'm a little confused - why would you set constraints from the cell to the table view? you can only managed the content of the cell, not it's location frame, the table view does that for you. You wanted to be able to set a dynamic height, this answer tells the table view to allow the cells to expand when necessary

Comment: @yar1vn This works like a champ on my iPhone layouts, but I have one screen that doesn't resize when loaded on iPad (sim or real). Any suggestions? Static table, static cells with dynamic heights, I am using your suggested code above and it works on iPhone but not iPad.

Comment: Is the table view not resizing or the cells? You might be missing constraint for the table to it's container view

Answer (score 0):

you can't change cell height with auto layout!!! only with `heightforrow...` you can change it!
first add `var size:SGSize!` to your code.
then add this code to view did load method to create an orientation notification:

```
 UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("orientationChanged:"), name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: UIDevice.currentDevice())
size = view.frame.size
```

then add this function to your code:

```
func orientationChanged(note: NSNotification) {
        var device: UIDevice = note.object as UIDevice
        switch(device.orientation){
        case UIDeviceOrientation.Portrait:
            size = view.frame.height  
            tableView.reloadData()
        case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
             size = view.frame.width
            tableView.reloadData()
        case UIDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight:
            size = view.frame.width
            tableView.reloadData()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

at the end set your cell height in

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 2) {
                return 25

        }
        else
        {
            return size.height
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which is better (or faster), to do what you wrote in the answer, or to do insert it in `viewWillTransitionToSize`?

Comment: That is not true! Auto layout will expand the cell height if set-up properly. Look at my answer

Comment: viewWillTransitionToSize is faster!

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. "Faster" or not, auto layout does support dynamic cell sizes. Also switching on the interface orientations should not be performed anymore